# How do I install Debian on Thinkpad T430 under UEFI?

Tags: debian, system-installation, thinkpad

I am trying to install Debian to a Thinkpad T430 that uses UEFI as a bootloader. The system is set to do a native UEFI boot. It is able to start GRUB from the installation media but upon choosing any installation option (both graphical and text installations) the screen goes black with visual glitches along the top. How do I get the kernel to boot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **disable** CSM in the T430's BIOS. It is not enough to disable legacy BIOS boot.